# HttpException No message on changing route to custom dashboard laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a controller `ManageController`:

```
public function index()
{
  return redirect()->route('manage.dashboard');
}

public function dashboard()
{
  return view('admin.manage.dashboard');
}
```

And Routes:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::prefix('manage')->middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator|editor')
->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', 'ManageController@index');
  Route::get('/dashboard', 'ManageController@dashboard')->name('manage.dashboard');
  Route::resource('/users', 'UserController');
  Route::resource('/permissions', 'PermissionController', ['except' => 'destroy']);
  Route::resource('/roles', 'RoleController', ['except' => 'destroy']);
});
```

And edited a line in `LoginController` to:
`protected $redirectTo = '/manage/dashboard';`

The trouble I'm having is I'm getting error

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ HttpException
No message`

after logging in into app with no message in `laravel.log` . And url is `http://localhost:8000/manage/dashboard`

Comment: `protected $redirectTo = '/manage/dashboard';` not `protected $redirectTo = route('manage.dashboard');` ? well, not sure.

Comment: @TanjaForsberg Maybe the problem is with `roles` middlewares(check if you have those specified roles), otherwise you can see stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

you don't have a route `/manage/dashboard`

Comment: Then what does `Route::prefix('manage')` do? Isn't a `manage` prefix for all routes in that group?